# Nilpotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $x \in R$.

Prove that if $x$ is nilpotent then $1-x \in R$ is unit.

May I use the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots
$$
and then say that since $x$ is nilpotent, there exist $n$ such that $x^n=0$, and of course $x^{n+1}=0$, and therefore this sum is finite and $1/(1-x)$ is a well defined element.

will that prove compile ?

Comment: The other answers have discussed the correctness of your solution, so I'll discuss what is incorrect about it.

When you write
$$1+x+x^2 + \dots,$$
the "$\dots$" implies there is some notion of a limit or distance in your ring, which is generally not the case.

Comment: I'm aware of the syntax problem with this proof, just seems hard to me to find the multiplicative element of 1-x without thinking of 1/(1-x) as geometric series, which is true only for |X| < 1, how may i find and think of finding this multiplicative from other views ?

Comment: @mathftw In a general ring you may not even have absolute value, divisions as you wrote, etc.

Comment: I find it a useful *heuristic* to find the right expression to check, but you still need to validate the resulting expression with the definition of a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better, find the multiplicative element of $\;1-x\;$, which is what must be done when dealing with these things in ring theory. Suppose $\;x^n=0\;$ , then

$$(1-x)(1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1})=1-x^n=1$$

Comment: @mathftw Simply knowing the sum of a geometric series: $$1+r+r^2+\ldots+r^{n-1}=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$

Answer (score 2):

$(1-x)(1+x..+x^n)=1$ if $x^{n+1}=0$.